# Is using a HTMLElement as an event emitter for generic class a good idea?

Tags: javascript, dom-events, es6-class

Code is better than a thousand words:

```
class MyClass {
    constructor(company, track) {
        // Use native DOM event emitter built in in any HTMLElement instance
        this.event_emmiter = document.createElement("span");
    }
    /**
     * 
     * @param {String} name
     * @param {Function} callback
     * @param {boolean} once whether the callback should be removed after first dispatch
     */
    addEventListener(name, callback, once) {
        this.event_emmiter.addEventListener(name, callback, typeof once == "object" ? once : { once: once === true });
    }
    removeEventListener(name, callback) {
        this.event_emmiter.removeEventListener(name, callback);
    }
}
```

I am aware of the [EventEmitter2](https://github.com/asyncly/EventEmitter2) framework, but it's a big dependency unsuitable for my current project. The project will never need to run outside browser or in web-worker. It's frontend for an audio player.

This is how I trigger an event:

```
this.event_emitter.dispatchEvent(
    new CustomEvent("name", { detail: {/* data */} })
);
```

So do you think this is a good idea? Or is there some horrible drawback?

Comment: @trincot Good question. I use the `CustomEvent` interface.

Comment: I don't see a horrible drawback.

Answer (score 0):

I don’t think that’s a good idea, no. Pick an implementation that’s as light as you need with the behaviour you need instead. For example, here’s something short that adds listeners at most once and allows listeners to remove future listeners on the same event:

```
class EventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this.listeners = new Map();
    }

    addListener(listener) {
        this.listeners.set(listener, listener);
    }

    removeListener(listener) {
        this.listeners.delete(listener);
    }

    once(listener) {
        if (this.listeners.has(listener)) {
            return;
        }

        const wrapper = e => {
            if (this.listeners.get(listener) === wrapper) {
                this.removeListener(wrapper);
            }

            listener(e);
        };

        this.listeners.set(listener, wrapper);
    }

    emit(e) {
        this.listeners.forEach(value => {
            value(e);
        });
    }
}
```

with named events:

```
class MultiEventEmitter {
    constructor() {
        this.emitters = Object.create(null);
    }

    getEmitter(name) {
        return this.emitters[name] || (this.emitters[name] = new EventEmitter());
    }

    addListener(name, listener) {
        this.getEmitter(name).addListener(listener);
    }

    removeListener(name, listener) {
        this.getEmitter(name).removeListener(listener);
    }

    once(name, listener) {
        this.getEmitter(name).once(listener);
    }

    emit(name, e) {
        this.getEmitter(name).emit(e);
    }
}
```

(That’s to give an idea of the size of the dependency; you should probably pick an npm package or something, though. Just make sure to check how it behaves in odd situations if they can arise in your case.)